# JavaScript array all value show 0 when print using console.log

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

If my nested array named **alpha** has exactly same value as the object property in **bravo**, the object value should be added into the **cost**. After all the values in the fist nested array had finished went through the for-loop, the cost should be pushed into an array named **charlie**. However, I run **console.log(charlie)** and find that all values in **charlie** are **0**, why this happens?

```js
    var alpha = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e"]]
     
    var bravo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 999 }

    var charlie = [];

        //For-loop 1
        for(let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++){

            var cost = 0;

            const currentAlpha = alpha[i];

            //For-loop 2
            for(let j = 0; j < currentAlpha.length; j++){

                //For-loop 3
                for (let x in bravo) {
                    if (currentAlpha[j] == Object.getOwnPropertyNames(bravo[x])){
                        cost += bravo[x];
                    }
                  }
            }

          charlie.push(cost);

        }
        
        console.log(charlie);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the built-in array function [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate the `alpha` array and then [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to sum the `bravo` values for each element in those arrays:

```js
const alpha = [
  ["a", "b", "c"],
  ["d", "e"]
]

const bravo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 999 }

const charlie = alpha.map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  acc += (bravo[el] ?? 0)
  return acc
}, 0)
)

console.log(charlie)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your If statement is never true.

You can do it like this.

```js
 var alpha = [["a", "b", "c"],["d", "e"]]
         
        var bravo = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4, e: 999 }
    
        var charlie = [];
    
            //For-loop 1
            for(let i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++){
    
                var cost = 0;
    
                const currentAlpha = alpha[i];
    
                //For-loop 2
                for(let j = 0; j < currentAlpha.length; j++){
    
                    //For-loop 3
                    for (let x in bravo) {
                    
                        if (currentAlpha[j] == x ){
                            cost += bravo[x];
                        }
                      }
                }
    
              charlie.push(cost);
    
            }
            
            console.log(charlie);
```